# Mixing C and assembly code in a simple 32 bit kernel

Tags: c, assembly, x86, kernel, osdev

I have a simple implementation of a 32 bit kernel that I have written in C (it's a freestanding implementation): (The VGA screen is in 80*25 color text mode)

```
#include<stdint.h>

#define COLOR 0x39
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xb8000

uint32_t get_cursor();
void set_cursor(uint32_t);

void puts(char* Message);
void kmain()
{
        puts("This is a test message..");
        return;
}

void puts(char* Message)
{
        uint32_t pointer = get_cursor();
        pointer <<= 1;
        char* VGA_CURSOR = (char*) VIDEO_MEMORY;
        VGA_CURSOR += pointer;
        while   (*Message)
        {
                *VGA_CURSOR = *Message;
                Message++;
                VGA_CURSOR ++;
                *VGA_CURSOR = COLOR;
                VGA_CURSOR ++;
        }
        VGA_CURSOR -= VIDEO_MEMORY;
        pointer = (uint32_t)VGA_CURSOR;
        pointer >>= 1;
        set_cursor(pointer);
}
```

The set_cursor and get_cursor functions are defined in assembly as such:

```
[bits 32]
[global set_cursor]
[global get_cursor]

set_cursor:   ;ebx is the location

        mov ebx,[esp+0x18]
        mov al, 0x0f ;Refer to the index register table port mapping for CRT (low byte)
        mov dx, 0x3d4 ; port number CRT index
        out dx,al   ;Write 0x0f in port 0x3D4  --- note that the port registers are 1 byte in size
        mov dx,0x3d5 ;port number CRT data
        mov al,bl
        out dx,al

        mov al, 0x0e ;Refer to the index register table port mapping for CRT (high byte)
        mov dx, 0x3d4 ; port number CRT index
        out dx,al
        mov dx,0x3d5 ;port number CRT data
        mov al,bh
        out dx,al

        ret

get_cursor:
        mov al, 0x0f ;Refer to the index register table port mapping for CRT (low byte)
        mov dx, 0x3d4 ; port number CRT index
        out dx,al   ;Write 0x0f in port 0x3D4  --- note that the port registers are 1 byte in size
        mov dx,0x3d5 ;port number CRT data
        in al,dx   ;Store the low byte in al -- Hardware forced to use al
        mov bl,al

        mov al, 0x0e ;Refer to the index register table port mapping for CRT (high byte)
        mov dx, 0x3d4 ; port number CRT index
        out dx,al   ;Write 0x0f in port 0x3D4  --- note that the port registers are 1 byte in size
        mov dx,0x3d5 ;port number CRT data
        in al,dx   ;Store the high byte in al -- Hardware forced to use al
        mov bh,al   ;Store the high byte in bh

        xor eax,eax
        mov ax,bx

        ret
```

Here, the getcursor function seems to work fine (It gets the value of the cursor that ranges from 0 to 80*25)
I know that the implementation of setcursor is right too. (I've used it in pure assembly codes). I believe that there is an error in passing of the values on the stack.
Where could I have been wrong?

Comment: `mov ebx,[esp+0x18]` would be incorrect. In the 32-bit ABI parameters are passed on the stack. At ESP+0 is the return address (put there by a `call` instruction or equivalent). ESP+4 would be the first parameter. What happens if you use `mov ebx,[esp+4]` ?

Comment: +4 because the IP is a 32 bit one?

Comment: Also, EBX is call-preserved in the calling convention GCC `-m32` uses.  Use `movzx ecx, word [esp+4]` to load 2 bytes from just above the return address into ECX, instead of EBX.  (Or use `gcc -m32 -mregparm=3` to make it pass args in EAX, ECX, EDX registers (in that order IIRC), instead of the inefficient stack-args conventions.)

Comment: ESP+4 because the return address is 32-bits (4 bytes) (The return address is ESP+0, ESP+1, ESP+2, ESP+3

Comment: Also: `xor eax,eax` ; `mov ax,bx`??  Did you forget about `movzx eax, bx`?  Or even better, read the inputs in the other order (if that's possible) so you have the right value in AL at the end, and can just mov the other one into AH.  (And xor-zero EAX at the start of the function so that will leave it zero-extended).  And again, you probably don't want to destroy your caller's EBX.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That solves it! But suppose I had a second parameter, the esp offset would be determined by the size of the first one? +0x8 in my case? (4+4)

Comment: @PeterCordes So ebx can be used by the caller? How is this done?

Comment: Correct. And yes, the second parameter in this case would be at ESP+8 if you added a second parameter. Heed Peter's advice about fixing the use of _EBX_ as it is a non-volatile register. The 32-bit ABI requires you to save and restore any of the non-volatile registers if you use them. The non-volatile registers are EBX, ESI, EDI, EBP, and ESP.

Comment: @PeterCordes The reason for this kind of code is that I'd been using a piece of assembly code from my pure assembly days... and I wanted the fastest modification to quickly switch to c... Also I didn't know about movzx...

Comment: A function that wants to use EBX will push ebx at the start, and pop ebx at the end, so it can use it without destroying *its* caller's value.  Look at gcc output.  (If you're not familiar with the concept of call-preserved regs, a kernel might be too much to start with...)  BTW, If you're using GCC, use  `inb` / `outb` C macros function wrapper for inline asm for so you don't have to write that part in asm yourself at all, and can just use C shifts and OR to assemble an integer out of 2 bytes.  GCC might even come with such wrappers in a header somewhere, or examples should be easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the place the error existed was in the function parameter passing.
An objdump of the c code shows this in the place where the function is called:

```
  73:   ff 75 f0                pushl  -0x10(%ebp)
  76:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   77 <printf+0x5e>
  7b:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
```

[ebp-0x10] is my *pointer*
 variable...
The place where I got confused was probably the **add esp,0x10**. Even though I'd passed only 1 parameter (of 4 bytes), it seemed to *keep* 16 bytes on the stack?

However, looks like [esp] was the return address (4 bytes = 32 bits), [esp + 4] is the first parameter.... Maybe the 16 bytes were for proper alignment

Thanks to Michael Petch: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch
and Peter Cordes: https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes for their comments!